# How to print the contents of a query to a blank page

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello everyone,

Just a quick question, I am querying a database and i was wondering can anyone help me print the results of the query from a database into a new tab window. I think i have an idea on how to do it, but can someone guide me. So before i call the *$statement->execute();* function in php should i create a  tag?

So for example,

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $stat = (!empty($_GET['stat']) ? trim($_GET['stat']) : '');    

try {
            $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=utf8', $databasehost, $dbname);

    $database_handler = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
  ));
        $statement = $database_handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE bin = "Teller";)

    $statement->bindParam(':stat', $stat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();


    $queryResult = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['queryResult'] = $queryResult;;
    $statement->execute();
  }

   catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Is this possible? Please mind my lack of knowledge, i am a beginner in php.

Comment: I got the execution part down, it is just displaying the results in a new tab window, oppose to displaying it in the same window.

Comment: target="_blank" as you have is correct. however you will need to write this dynamic file output and put the correct href to point at the filename. please post your php code for writing to the file

Comment: Oh thanks for that info, I still am confused a bit. So correct me if i am wrong, you're saying i should put the my .php file extension in the href ? so <a href "myfile.php" target = "_blank"></a>

Comment: not quite. im saying you need to have some php code which generates/writes to a html file eg. some_dynamic_file.html which you then need to have a link to like <a href="some_dynamic_file.html" target="_blank">click here for output</a>

Comment: few starter points: you should remove $statement->execute at bottom, add error handling around the other statement->execute ( what if statement->execute fails ). also i think the standard practice is to call fetch ( not fetchAll ) and use a loop around this to write your data. see the accepted answer in this thread : [loop-through-a-mysql-query-via-pdo-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159924/how-do-i-loop-through-a-mysql-query-via-pdo-in-php). after youve adjusted your code try printing your output in the same page first ( and later modify to write to file and link to that )

Comment: Ahh uhm, I do not know how to write to a file and link to that file in php, that where my issue is, outputting the file in the same page works for me already, it's just writing to a file and linking to it, I do not know how to do that.

Comment: for writing to file use [fwrite](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fwrite.asp). for linking to the file, you just need to echo an anchor tag linking to the file you just wrote with the special open in new tab _blank attribute. but you need to write a valid html string with fwrite