# check all the date values stored in database with system date

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP(PDO), MYSQL. I have a number of `date` values stored in my database and am trying to compare my system date with date values stored in the database one by one.

I can compare a single date value, but I am not able to compare all the date values. I want to compare all the date values from the database with my system date and if it matches it should echo.

I know it would be under loop concept, but I don't know how to run loop on that. Is this the correct concept or what?

```
 $sysdate= date("Y-m-d");//system date;

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM setremainder"); 
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->fetch();
$r1=$result['datetime'];
```

comparing systemdate with datbase value

```
 if ($r1==$sysdate) {
    echo success";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through a MySQL query via PDO in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159924/how-do-i-loop-through-a-mysql-query-via-pdo-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

How about using `WHERE` clause *(it will also be faster)*, which will return only matched records.

```
$sysdate= date("Y-m-d");//system date;

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM setremainder where datetime = :datetime");
$stmt->execute(["datetime" => $sysdate]);
// Above 2 line will return records that only matches the record
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    echo "success";
}
```

And since you mentioned you only need to print something when it is matched with records perhaps, you can also use `COUNT()` function that will only count number of rows that matches your statement with given system date.

```
$sysdate= date("Y-m-d");//system date;

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM setremainder where datetime = :datetime");
$stmt->execute(["datetime" => $sysdate]);
// Above 2 line will return records that only matches the record
$number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

### NOTE:

Make sure your DB column date format and extracted system date param are either same or compatible

Comment: @arun if my answer solved your problem, consider marking it your answer.