# Only getting one result when creating nested JSON from MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, nested

Im very new to both mysql and php.

So I'm making 2 sql queries and binding them together with kampid as the from both the queries.

everything is in the same table and not in different so what I know I cannot

```
            $array1 = array();
            $array2 = array();

            $sql = "select r.kampid, q.trade from (
            select kampid
            from posts where kampid != 0
            group by kampid
            ) r
            join
            (
             select p.kampid, p.trade
             from
             (
              select kampid, trade, count(*) as cnt
              from posts
              group by kampid, trade
              ) p
             join
             (
              select kampid, max(cnt) as maxcnt
              from (
                    select kampid, trade, count(*) as cnt
                    from posts
                    group by kampid, trade) x
              group by kampid) y
             on y.kampid = p.kampid and y.maxcnt = p.cnt
             ) q
            on r.kampid = q.kampid";

            //prepare statement
            $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

            //catch error
            if (!$statement){
                throw new Exception($statement->error);
            }
            $statement->execute();

            //result we got in execution
            $result = $statement->get_result();

            // each line append to array new row one by one when it is found
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){



               // $array1[$row["kampid"]][] = array( $row['trade'] );
                $array1['kampid'] = $row['kampid'];
                $array1['trade'] = array($row['trade']);
                $array1['department'] = array();






                $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(posts.companyName) AS companies,
                posts.kampid, posts.department, SUM(posts.people)AS total
                           FROM posts WHERE kampid = '".$row['kampid']."' GROUP BY posts.department, posts.kampid ORDER BY posts.kampid, posts.department ASC";

                           //prepare statement
                           $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql2);

                           //catch error
                           if (!$statement){
                               throw new Exception($statement->error);
                           }
                           $statement->execute();
                           //result we got in execution
                           $result = $statement->get_result();

                while ($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()){



                    $array2['department'] = $row2['department'];
                    $array2['companies'] = $row2['companies'];
                    $array2['total'] = $row2['total'];
                    array_push($array1[department], $array2);



                      }



            }


            $output_arr = array();
            array_push($output_arr, $array1);

            $jsonData = json_encode($output_arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


echo $jsonData; 

        }
```

and I get this output:

```
[
  {
    "kampid": 1901,
    "trade": [
      "Åkeri"
    ],
    "department": [
      {
        "department": 3,
        "companies": 8,
        "total": 63
      },
      {
        "department": 4,
        "companies": 38,
        "total": 114
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

but the json stops after the first "kampid", when there are more "kampid" 1902, 1903 etc

the result I want is as follow:

```
[
  {
    "kampid": 1901,
    "trade": [
      "Truck"
    ],
    "department": [
      {
        "department": 3,
        "companies": 8,
        "total": 63
      },
      {
        "department": 4,
        "companies": 38,
        "total": 114
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "kampid": 1902,
    "trade": [
      "Mechanic"
    ],
    "department": [
      {
        "department": 3,
        "companies": 8,
        "total": 63
      },
      {
        "department": 4,
        "companies": 38,
        "total": 114
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "kampid": 1903,
    "trade": [
      ""
    ],
    "department": [
      {
        "department": 3,
        "companies": 8,
        "total": 63
      },
      {
        "department": 4,
        "companies": 38,
        "total": 114
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: got answer to move  "array_push($output_arr, $array1);" inside the outer loop, but for consisted result I needed to rename the second $result and $statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through a MySQL query via PDO in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159924/how-do-i-loop-through-a-mysql-query-via-pdo-in-php)

Comment: Your push into $output_arr comes to late, you are only doing that after _both_ of those loops, whereas it should happen _inside_ of the outer loop. (The initialization as an empty array belongs before the whole thing then of course.)

Comment: That's also an impressively complex query for someone who is new to MySQL - can you describe what its end goal is? There may be a simpler route than the query you currently have.

Comment: @misorude gives solution to the issue. Other than this, this code has too much query calls to MySQL and could cause script execution break. Consider optimizing code.

Comment: You could wrap specific parts of your code into individual functions.  That way it's easier to keep track of what they do.  For example, `getAllKamps()`, `getCompaniesForKamp($kampid)`, etc.  I didn't follow your code so well, so sorry if these function names are wrong.

Comment: @LukeBriggs, I got like 5 columns of data, the first query does 1 one thing but that query was the most complex thing I've ever tried. Count occurrences of a string in a column grouped by another column, and everything with count(*) did not work so that was the solution I found
-----------------------------
Column A | Column B
1901         | Hello
1902         | Hello
1901         | Hi
1901         | Hello
1902         | Hi
1902         | Hello
1902         | Hi
1901         | Hello

Result: 
1901     most occurring: Hello
1902    most occurring: Hi

Comment: @misorude, thanks! that solved my issue. Now it's time for optimization now when I know it works =D Thanks a lot!